# What is the use of a state management library in a SSR-application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im using NextJS as library to serve a SSR application. In the documentation and examples I read a lot about using a state management library for this. I am used to using a state management library on a client-side rendered application, but I dont really see the added value in a SSR application. On the client I would use this to store settings like profile, UI-state and maybe some results from API-calls. Whenever I navigate, this store stays intact. However, in a SSR application when a navigation occurs, a new request comes in, where all the JavaScript gets loaded again, right? Which means my store will get build from zero again.

Comment: in next js, only the first load uses SSR, afterwards other pages load like a regular SPA (unless you use getServerProps in any of the pages, but still only that function will be executed on the server, while the page will be preloaded as a SPA page.)

Comment: But for most apps, I'd drop the use of redux, mobx, in favor of the context API + hooks, as redux can cause negative impact in  the app performance and first load times. Use it only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

State management in SSR is mostly to preload the state which the client side hydrates from.

The benefit of this is for example if you would want to load something from database on first page load, then you can do this on the server by rendering the values into the view returned to the browser. Therefore the client side does not have to load async from a backend.

[Here is the redux eample](https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering#inject-initial-component-html-and-state)

```
function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering/#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(
            /</g,
            '\\u003c'
          )}
        </script>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}
```

If you plan to give this a go be careful with `JSON.stringify(preloadedState)` that is an XSS vulnerability